Getting user authentication for a network proxy in Electron 29.3
I have an Electron app that gets images from an external URL. I am having issues getting the authentication for the user who is using the app. I want to have something like this appear when the Electron app opens.
I have tried using the prompt() function but it is disabled in Electron.
I also tried using environment variables but found it is not easily accessible for the end user
app.on("login", async (event, webContents, request, authInfo, callback) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    callback(process.env.PROXYUSERNAME, process.env.PROXYPASSWORD);
});

